# How to load android layout as main page in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So, I need to load an android axml (which is inside project.android->resources->layout) but I don't know how to get that on the cross-platform project. Is there any way for me to do something like this:

```
    public App()
    {
        MainPage = new Project.Android.Resources.Layout.Main();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

If so, please let me know. If not, is there any work around?

Comment: that would really defeat the purpose of having a cross platform project, wouldn't it?

Comment: I understand, but I need to separate a couple views for them to be platform specific

Comment: then use a custom renderer

Comment: How can I do that? I've been searching for a while now.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Like what was said earleir, you are really breaking what Xamarin.Forms stands for and should probably reconsider your approach if your find yourself as you are.

Comment: I'm trying to test an android specific code (Firebase messaging) but I cannot get to replace the already set main page for the android main.axml as the documentation asks me to (I'm new to Xamarin, so I don't really know any other way to do it).

Comment: There is no need to  load an android axml in `PCL` to implement your feature, could you please share the documentation link address? I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/ . I cannot  get to show the layout/Main.axml